# Where can someone buy a refurbished iPhone?

Tags: iphone

When I go to Apple's [webpage for refurbished and clearance products](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals), I can find links to buy Macs, iPods and iPads, but none for buying refurbished iPhones.

Is it possible to buy a refurbished iPhone:

- online, on the Apple Store?
- in a physical Apple Store?
- online or offline with a phone carrier?
- other options?

Answer (score 2):

If you live in the UK (and presumably Europe), [SmartFoneStore](http://www.smartfonestore.com/) is a very good place to start looking for refurbished smartphones including iPhones. I believe the refurbs are classified as Grade A, B and C and are priced accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to buy a refurbished iPhone direct from Apple, **when they have one in stock**.  You can even save shipping by selecting to pick it up at an Apple store.  Sometimes volume sellers on eBay have them.  If you don't buy it from Apple, it may be refurbished by someone else and/or not have the one-year warranty that Apple always puts on their refurbs.